# JavaFx dynamic column values

Tags: javafx, java-8, javafx-8, dynamic-columns, treetableview

I have a `TreeTableView<MyCustomRow>` and I want to add columns dynamically. In `MyCustomRow` i have a `Map<Integer, SimpleBooleanProperty>`  with the values in the row. I'm adding the new column this way:

```
private TreeTableColumn<MyCustomRow, Boolean> newColumn() {
    TreeTableColumn<MyCustomRow, Boolean> column = new TreeTableColumn<>();
    column.setId(String.valueOf(colNr));
    column.setPrefWidth(150);
    column.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().getValue().getValue(colNr));
    column.setCellFactory(factory -> new CheckBoxTreeTableCell());
    column.setEditable(true);
    colNr++;
    return column; 
}
```

Then `table.getColumns().add(newColumn())`.

The problem is when I check a `CheckBox` in a row, all CheckBoxes in that row become checked.  Here is the code for my row:

```
public class MyCustomRow {
    private Map<Integer, SimpleBooleanProperty> values = new HashMap<>();

    public MyCustomRow(Map<Integer, Boolean> values) {
        values.entrySet().forEach(entry -> this.values
                .put(entry.getKey(), new SimpleBooleanProperty(entry.getValue())));
    }

    public SimpleBooleanProperty getValue(Integer colNr) {
        if (!values.containsKey(colNr)) {
            values.put(colNr, new SimpleBooleanProperty(false));
        }
        return values.get(colNr);
    }

}
```

So I set the value of the cell depending on the `colNr`, i also tried to debug and it seems the values are different in the `values` map, so I have no idea why all the checkBoxes are checked when I check just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line,

```
column.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().getValue().getValue(colNr));
```

The handler is called when the cells are shown. Hence all of `colNr` are the newest value, the boolean property of the last index is associated with all cells.

To call the handler with the value at the time of `newColumn()` is called, for example:

```
final Integer colNrFixed = colNr;
column.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().getValue().getValue(colNrFixed));
// ...
colNr++;
```